How to use dependency injection when I want to create many http clients with different configuration to connect to different servers?
I have one application that uses two http clients, because it will send request to two different servers. The configuration of each server and the address is get from the configuration file.
But I would like to leave open the door to can add more clients.
So I have a client class like this:
public class TestClient
{
    private HttpClient Client { get; }
    public TestClient(HttpClient client)
    {
        Client = client;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> CallAsync(CancellationToken cancellation = default)
    {
        return client.GetAsync("/", cancellation);
    }
}

And I can register as dependency in this way:
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddHttpClient("test", httpClient =>
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost");                    
});

services.AddScoped<TestClient>();

All this code is from this question.
My doubt is that in dependency injection, if I am not wrong, it is always created the instances of a type in the same way, so both would have the same base address.
How could do in this case?
Perhaps I could use a factory with a GetHttpClients() method, so I would register in this factory as dependency.  This method would created one http client for each client class. Something like that:
public IConfigurationManager()
{
    public List<EndPoints> GetEndPoints();
}



public class ClientTestFactory
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _paramConfigurationManager;

    //IConfigurationManager is injected as depedency and gives access to the endspoints defined in the configuration.
    public ClientTestFactory(IConfiguration paramConfigurationManager)
    {
        pubilc List<ClientTest> GetClients()
        {
            List<ClientTest> clients = [];

            List<EndPoints> endpoints = _paramConfigurationManager.GetEndPoints();

            foreach(EndPoints iterator in endpoints)
            {
                HttpClient httpClient = //create with IHttpClientFactory or some way.
                ClientTest client = //create client passing the http client
                clients.Add(client);
            }


            return clients;
        }
    }
}

And I register the factory instead of the http client:
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddSingleton<IClientTestFactory, ClientTestFactory>();
services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationManager, ConfigurationManager>();

But I don't know if it is a good practice to use a factory to create the http clients.
If there are another solutions, how could I create many clients with different configuration?

You might want to check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-8.0#named-clients where you can register services with a name and request a specific service with the same name.

I don't know if this will answer your question, however, without complicating your life, you can use IHttpClientFactory (only if in the Program.cs you first do - builder.Services.AddHttpClient();) directly in the class that will act as a service to go to call N Api, so for example (obviously an interface will have to be created for the service1 methods, I won't include it so as not to complicate the code):
In Program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Services.AddScoped<Service1>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<Service2>();


In Service1.cs
public class Service1{

private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
//IHttpClientFactory it's available automatically when you do builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

public Service1(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    _configuration = configuration;
}

//then this method will be called in all your code 
public async Task<Dictionary<string,object>?> Service1MethodX()
{
    //the using will close automatically the httpClient when you have a response
    using (HttpClient httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient()) 
    {
        //make your api call and return the value
    }
}

//the same thing will be done for service2, etc


In case of HttpClient there are many ways how you can create one. The named client and typed client are documented on Microsoft Learn website. Unfortunately the named and typed client are not even mentioned. (BTW I've just filed a PR against https://github.com/dotnet/docs/ to address this problem.)
The named and typed client is a combination of the other two. Mainly it allows you to register a named, pre-configured wrapper around HttpClient into your DI. That means you can register the same typed client multiple times with different name.
Even though the registration part is straightforward the usage is a bit clumsy.
So, let me show you how to use it properly.
The typed client
public interface ITestClient
{
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> CallEndpointWithGivenStatusCodeAsync(HttpStatusCode statusCode);
}

public class TestClient: ITestClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient Client;
    public TestClient(HttpClient client) => Client = client;

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CallEndpointWithGivenStatusCodeAsync(HttpStatusCode statusCode)
    {
        var requestPrefixUrl = Client.BaseAddress.Host.Contains("bin") ? "/status" : "";
        return await Client.GetAsync($"{requestPrefixUrl}/{(int)statusCode}");
    }
}


The requestPrefixUrl is a workaround to support the following two websites:

HttpBin: https://httpbin.org/status/500
HttpStat.Us: https://httpstat.us/500


Even though you can set the BaseAddress to https://httpbin.org/status but the /status path will be omitted from the BaseAddress.

Registering named and typed clients
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<ITestClient, TestClient>("HttpBin", 
   client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://httpbin.org/"));

builder.Services.AddHttpClient<ITestClient, TestClient>("HttpStat", 
   client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://httpstat.us/"));


I've registered the same TestClient twice with different names and different BaseAddress settings.

The usage
app.MapGet("/status", async (
    [FromServices] IHttpClientFactory namedClientFactory, 
    [FromServices] ITypedHttpClientFactory<TestClient> namedTypedClientFactory) =>
{
    var namedClient = namedClientFactory.CreateClient("HttpStat"); //Or HttpBin
    var client = namedTypedClientFactory.CreateClient(namedClient);

    var res = await client.CallEndpointWithGivenStatusCodeAsync(
       HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    return res.StatusCode.ToString();
});


I've used a minimal API for the sake of conciseness
As you can see you have to inject IHttpClientFactory and ITypedHttpClientFactory as well

The ITypedHttpClientFactory resides inside the Microsoft.Extensions.Http assembly



Two call outs here:

The parameter of the ITypedHttpClientFactory should be the implementation TestClient, not the abstraction ITestClient

If you would use ITestClient then you would get InvalidOperationException


First you have to create the named client and then use that to create the typed client via namedTypedClientFactory.CreateClient call

